# Vue.js, Interval timer on v-for

Tags: javascript, vue.js, intervals, v-for

So I'm loading in some data and I'm rendering it to the DOM with a v-for loop in my template. Now I would like to make the data appear at an interval. i.e; a new message shows up every second.

The only way I could think of is to hide all the messages with css and make them (re)appear by unhiding them one at a time. However, I don't think this is the right way to go about this.

So if any of you has a suggestion for how I should go about this, would be great!

Answer (score 2):

There are multiple ways to handle this. You could use two arrays. One to hold the data you want to show and the other to show it. Then put an interval function in the `created` function that will transfer the items from the hold array to the show array. Like so:

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
    todos: [
    ],
    soonTodo: [
          { text: "Learn JavaScript", done: false },
      { text: "Learn Vue", done: false },
      { text: "Play around in JSFiddle", done: true },
      { text: "Build something awesome", done: true }
    ],
    interval: null,
  },
  methods: {
   toggle: function(todo){
     todo.done = !todo.done
    }
  },
  created() {
   this.interval = setInterval(() => {
     if (this.soonTodo.length) {
       this.todos.push(this.soonTodo.shift());
      } else {
       clearInterval(this.interval);
      }
    }, 1000)
  }
})
```

```css
body {
  background: #20262E;
  padding: 20px;
  font-family: Helvetica;
}

#app {
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 4px;
  padding: 20px;
  transition: all 0.2s;
}

li {
  margin: 8px 0;
}

h2 {
  font-weight: bold;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}

del {
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.16/vue.min.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <h2>Todos:</h2>
  <ol>
    <li v-for="todo in todos">
      <label>
        <input type="checkbox"
          v-on:change="toggle(todo)"
          v-bind:checked="todo.done">

        <del v-if="todo.done">
          {{ todo.text }}
        </del>
        <span v-else>
          {{ todo.text }}
        </span>
      </label>
    </li>
  </ol>
</div>
```

Another way, if you want to alter your data structure, is to have a `show` property on your data that `v-show` could bind to. Then your interval function would just run through the array each time setting that property to `true` until each item is showing.

```
// JS 
{ text: "Learn JavaScript", done: false, show: false }

// HTML
<li v-for="todo in todos" v-show="todo.show">
  <label>
    <input type="checkbox"
      v-on:change="toggle(todo)"
      v-bind:checked="todo.done">

    <del v-if="todo.done">
      {{ todo.text }}
    </del>
    <span v-else>
      {{ todo.text }}
    </span>
  </label>
</li>
```

Comment: No problem. Happy to help.

Comment: @Steven I added a second way to accomplish this as well.

Comment: Thanks dude! I'm gonna check it out!